# WiFi on Ubuntu 10.04 stopped working

Tags: 10.04, wireless, thinkpad

Yesterday my WiFi just stopped working on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS system. I am on an IBM X60 ThinkPad.

Comment: we need to have more information about this like type of driver and all .

Answer (score 0):

it is pretty much easy to get wifi switched off accidentally - ["Radio Frequency Kill Switch" is rather hidden below the front edge of the keyboard, it stops Wireless, Bluetooth and/or GSM/UMTS.](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/X60s)